# Explicit template specialization for const QString& results in unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, visual-c++, qt4

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>

// this is some sort of low-level C function
void lowLevelOpenFD(int fd)
{
    qDebug("Opened by fd: %d", fd);
}

// as well as this one
void lowLevelOpenName(const char *name)
{
    qDebug("Opened by name: %s", name);
}

// this is a wrapper around low-level functions
template<typename FileId>
void callLowLevelOpen(FileId id);

template<>
void callLowLevelOpen(const QString &fileName)
{
    lowLevelOpenName(QFile::encodeName(fileName).constData());
}

template<>
void callLowLevelOpen(int fd)
{
    lowLevelOpenFD(fd);
}

// this is the function where the most stuff happens
template<typename FileId>
void openInternal(FileId id)
{
    // lots of useful stuff goes here
    // now we call one of the two low level functions
    callLowLevelOpen(id);
    // more useful stuff
}

// this is high-level interface to the "open by name" function
void openFile()
{
    QString name = "file";
    openInternal(name);
}

// this is high-level interface to the "open by FD" function
void openFile(int fd)
{
    openInternal(fd);
}

int main()
{
    openFile();
    openFile(17);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the example above results in

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl callLowLevelOpen<class QString>(class QString)" (??$callLowLevelOpen@VQString@@@@YAXVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl openInternal<class QString>(class QString)" (??$openInternal@VQString@@@@YAXVQString@@@Z)
```

As far as I can see it happens because the compiler instantiates `openInternal<QString>()` when it's called from the first high-level overload. OK, so I thought and modified the code:

```
// this is high-level interface to the "open by name" function
void openFile()
{
    QString name = "file";
    openInternal<const QString&>(name);
}
```

The same problem. And I thought I told the compiler to instantiate the `openInternal<const QString&>`, so why it is still complains about `<class QString>`? I also tried this one:

```
// this is high-level interface to the "open by name" function
void openFile()
{
    QString name = "file";
    openInternal<const QString&>(static_cast<const QString&>(name));
}
```

Now this just looks silly and it still doesn't work. I can't explicitly specialize the `openInternal()` one because it's too large and the very point of this templated mess is to avoid unnecessary code duplication. I can't just rename the low level functions to turn them into overloaded ones, because they are in a third-party C library. The only thing I can do is to replace the first `callLowLevelOpen()` specialization with

```
template<>
void callLowLevelOpen(QString fileName)
{
    lowLevelOpenName(QFile::encodeName(fileName).constData());
}
```

Then it works. There is also virtually zero performance penalty so this is a perfectly valid workaround, but I just want to understand what is going on here.

The code above was just an SSCCE, the real code is [there](http://quazip.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/quazip/trunk/quazip/quazip/quagzipfile.cpp?revision=123&view=markup) if anyone interested. This particular issue is with the `gzopen()/gzdopen()`, `QuaGzipFilePrivate::open()` and `QuaGzipFile::open()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you actually change the signature, I think you actually don't want to specialize your function template but rather use overloading. Here is complete test program using `std::string` (I somehow prefer depending only on standard classes if the problem can be reproduced there as well):

```
#include <string>

template <typename T> void f(T);
// #define BROKEN
#if defined(BROKEN)
template <> void f(std::string const&) {}
#else
void f(std::string const&) {}
#endif

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    f(s);
}
```

If you `#defined BROKEN` in this code it won't work.

The reason for this behavior is that the compiler choose the overload based on the primary template. This will never add the `const&` part. Once this is done the compiler looks for potential specializations of the chosen overload. Since this will never have deduced the notation used for specialization this isn't picked up.

Why then is the `f<std::string const&>(s)` not picking up the specialization? For me it is, trying with both gcc and clang.

Comment: Awesome. It was really stupid of me to use templates for wrappers. I needed that for the main internal function to avoid code duplication, but there was no reason at all to use templates on lower levels. Now the code makes perfect sense. As for why it wasn't working, I suppose that's an MSVS bug, although I thought that maybe I overlooked something.